# Add data from API call to my current Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, object

I have an object (much larger than this but I'm shortening for readability) that looks like this

```
{
  "listings": [
    {
      "id": "5e0f9c42e84d27001f63f725",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "superior-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0f9c43e84d27001f63f93b",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "superior-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0f9c43e84d27001f63f96a",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "superior-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0f9c43e84d27001f63f999",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "superior-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0f9c43e84d27001f63f9c8",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "superior-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0f9c43e84d27001f63f9f7",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "superior-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0fadd0ff2ba100208700d0",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "classic-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0fadd1ff2ba1002087036c",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "classic-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0fadd1ff2ba100208703a1",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "classic-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5e0fadd1ff2ba100208703d6",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "classic-king",
      "calendar": "[]"
    },
  ]
}
```

I call an api to retrieve calendar data for specific dates and need to update my current object. My question is two parted -

1. How can I update only only the listings which have been returned from the call
2. The response comes back with what I'm pasting below.

```
[{ data: {date: "2020-04-29", listingId: "5e0f9c42e84d27001f63f725", status: "available", price: 95, …},
{ data: {date: "2020-04-30", listingId: "5e0f9c42e84d27001f63f725", status: "available", price: 96, …},
{ data: {date: "2020-05-01", listingId: "5e0f9c42e84d27001f63f725", status: "available", price: 99, …},
{ data: {date: "2020-04-29", listingId: "5e0f9c43e84d27001f63f93b", status: "available", price: 98, …},
{ data: {date: "2020-04-30", listingId: "5e0f9c43e84d27001f63f93b", status: "available", price: 99, …},
{ data: {date: "2020-05-01", listingId: "5e0f9c43e84d27001f63f93b", status: "available", price: 100, …}]
```

As you can see, depending on how many dates I'm requesting from the API, it returns each date as it's own object, even if for the same listingId. I need to update, for example, in the original object, listing with `id: 5e0f9c42e84d27001f63f725` to save the first 3 prices and dates as part of it's `calendar`. So it would look like

```
  {
      "id": "5e0f9c42e84d27001f63f725",
      "property": "ithaca",
      "unit": "superior-king",
      "calendar": [{ "date: ____, price: ____ },
                  { "date: ____, price: ____ },
                  { "date: ____, price: ____ }]
    },
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using basic JS Array methods like `.find()`, `.filter()` or `.map()`? Can we see your attempts?

Comment: I've tried with find, filter, map, reduce, forEach, can't get it right!

Comment: What have you tried means `can you show your code please` , so that we can find why you cen't get if right for you.

Comment: we can't see ur effort

Answer (score 2):

First your calendar is string instead of array

```
let newlistings = listings.map(listing => {
    return {...listing, calendar:[]}
})
```

Then, iterate your responseAPI

```
response.forEach(r => {
// check if the current data is existe in your listings
const indexListing = newListings.findIndex(listing => listing.id === r.data.listingId)
// if u find it, push in
if(indexListing !== -1) {
    listings.listings[indexListing].calendar.push(r.data);
}
})
```